# ¿Es válido decir "eso pasó ahorita"?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales, colombia

En Medellín (Colombia) se dice mucho "eso pasó ahorita", pero parecería ser que "ahora" o "ahorita" es más de futuro.

Ejemplo:

> Ellos vienen ahora.

o

> Ellos llegaron ahorita.

No suena bien.

Comment: Please considere that this varies regionally. It's OK to say it in some caribbean countries (and maybe somewhere else too), but in Chile and Argentina is not used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complicaciones con los tiempos aparte, yo pienso que el principal problema de "`ahorita`" es que en diferentes paises **se entiende de manera diferente**.

Me parece que se intercambian las nociones de `ahora` y de `ahorita`. Si en Cuba (y me parece que en España y otros países) `ahora` es ya, presente o futuro inmediato, `ahorita` es un futuro (o pasado) ligeramente mas relajado: dentro de un ratico, o hace un ratico.

Pero recuerdo haber creado pequeños problemas, cuando al decir "`ahorita` lo hago", me han mirado y preguntado: pero no lo ibas a hacer? A lo que he respondido: Si `ahorita`. Con lo que he logrado desesperar a la persona, que ha entendido que estoy diciendo que lo estoy haciendo `ahora`, en este mismo instante.

Solo que no recuerdo el país del otro

Comment: +1 por la ultima linea :)

Comment: En España no solemos usar *ahorita*. Es una de esas palabras que nos hacen pensar que nuestro interlocutor es hispanoamericano cuando la oímos.

Answer (score 8):

También escucho esto bien seguido. Ahorita no es una palabra ni concepto fácil de traducir.

Aunque sí se usa parar referirse a eventos en el futuro inmediato también se usa para expresar sucesos en el pasado reciente. Para mí si oigo a alguien decir algo como:

> Sí, lo vi ahorita en el Starbucks en Plaza.

En mi mente pienso:

> Sí lo ví hace rato en el Starbucks en Plaza.

Si tuviera que asignarle un periodo de tiempo diría que se refiere a hechos pasados dentro del presente dia y alrededor de dos o tres horas.

Al respecto a ahorita en el futuro nunca des por sentado que cuando alguien dice **si ahorita lo hago** quiere decir que eso va a pasar. Bien seguido se la usa para decir lo que seria el equivalente en ingles a **in a bit**. La idea es que dices que lo vas a hacer pero no sabes exactamente cuando, ni como, y a veces ni porque.

> Sure Mum, I'l clean my room in a bit.

Por eso cuando la usamos en referencia al futuro la usamos con el tiempo subjuntivo.

> Bueno ahorita que vayamos al mercado te compramos tus Micheladas (en ésta oración)

Comment: Sí, acabo de verlo en el Starbucks en Plaza.  This expresses the recent past.