# ¿Existe alguna diferencia entre "ahora" y "ahorita"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, significado, adverbios

En mi país, Argentina, no se usa la palabra "ahorita". En otros países como México veo que lo usan siempre o casi siempre, al punto que siempre pensé que era lo mismo que *ahora*.

Sin embargo, leyendo algunas páginas en inglés vi personas que las interpretaban de manera ligeramente diferente.

¿Existe entonces alguna diferencia entre *ahora* y *ahorita* o son exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Es válido decir “eso pasó ahorita”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3567/1674)

Comment: ¿Se usa *ahora mismo* en tu país, o no?

Comment: si, es como un ahora con más énfasis

Comment: @tchrist Creo yo que "ahora mismo" es un poquito diferente de "ahorita", por lo menos en México.

Comment: Relacionado (por el "-ito"): https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/33291/meaning-of-todito. También existe el uso de "-ingo/a" para enfatizar. Me parece que hace falta una pregunta acerca del este uso general y sus varios regionalismos.

Comment: Creo existe una diferencia más en cuestión de uso en México. Al expresar cuando alguien habla de algo que está sucediendo en presente, se diría *ahora mismo* acerca de una situación, pero cuando uno pregunta o responde de qué está haciendo en ese mismo momento, en vez de *ahora* sería *ahorita*. Y puede ser algo que está sucediendo en el momento exacto o que está a punto de suceder. -- *Pues ahora mismo estoy jugando un video juego, pero está en pausa y ahorita mismo le voy a dar una mordida a este sandwich.*

Comment: Parece que no soy el único que se hace esta pregunta: https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=720465372775720&set=a.280775806744681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo con Javier, para el contexto mexicano.  Voy a poner algunos ejemplos de uso, para distinguir entre *ahorita* y *ahora*.

1. Vamos a presenciar una obra de teatro en un espacio un tanto informal.

> --Ven a tomar tu asiento, Manuela, que ya va a empezar.
>
> --Sí, ahorita voy. (Está platicando [charlando] con una amiga, y quiere llegar al fin de la historia.)

"Ahorita voy" es menos inmediato que "Ya voy".  "Ahorita voy" es aproximadamente igual que "Voy en un momento", pero "Ahorita voy" está diseñado para tranquilizar a la otra persona, mientras que "Voy en un momento" es un poco más neutro de emociones.

"Ahora" se oiría más formal en un context así.

"Ahorita voy" puede comunicar varias emociones: *No me fastidies*, *No te preocupes, Se paciente, por favor.*

No sé cómo es en otros países, pero "ahorita voy" se usa mucho en México.

2. Anunciaron "Tercera llamada", y Manuela vino a sentarse, pero luego descubrieron problemas técnicos y la obra no ha comenzado todavía.  Diez minutos más tarde, se ve un movimiento en la escena.

> --Ahora sí ya van a empezar.

3. Mi hijo se comprometió a acompañarme al súpermercado.  Veo que está haciendo la tarea de matemáticas, pero yo ya quiero salir.  Le pregunto:

> --José Luis, ¿podemos irnos ahora?  ["¿Podemos irnos ya?" se oiría un poco impaciente.]  Si no, ya sabes, va a haber muchímisa gente.
>
> --No, sí, ahoritita vamos.  Nomás me falta un problema más.  Me permites, dos minutos, y ya.

Answer (score 4):

Al menos en Cuba "ahorita" se refiere a un momento en el pasado o en el futuro muy cercano.

- Ahorita voy para el trabajo.
- Llegué ahorita.

Answer (score 4):

En Colombia es ligeramente diferente:

- *Ahora* es para este momento.
- *Ahorita* se usa para algo que está muy cerca de pasar.

Ej: *Ahora no puedo hacer el ejercicio. Ahorita lo hago.*

Answer (score 2):

En Honduras lo utilizamos diferente, por ejemplo:
El ahorita lo sentimos de modo inmediato.
Y el ahora es como decir "hoy" así que ai te dicen "ahora lo hago" te están diciendo que lo van hacer en el dia de hoy pero no hay una hora fija

Answer (score 1):

En Perú significan los mismo, ciertamente alguien te puede decir, limpia la mesa! Y tú le puedes responder 'ahorita lo hago' pero también le puedes responder 'ahora lo hago' y no hay diferencia en el mensaje que quieres dar. También puedo decir 'ahorita estoy respondiendo una pregunta' o 'ahora estoy respondiendo una pregunta'

Answer (score -2):

No hay diferencia, simplemente es un diminutivo. Pero expresa la misma necesidad

Comment: Esta respuesta es mejorable en bastantes sentidos: ¿En qué te basas para dar esta respuesta? ¿En qué región se basa esta respuesta?

Comment: En México, definitivamente, son diferentes.