# Uso de "ahorita" en México

Tags: méxico, tiempos-verbales

Me gustaría saber si el uso de "ahorita" en México puede ser en pasado en una narración, como algo que ocurre en medio de ella:

> Ahorita llegaron los muchachos a la casa

Comment: Bienvenido Nicolás. Has revisado preguntas relacionadas ya existentes como [¿Es válido decir “eso pasó ahorita”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3567/5481) y [¿Existe alguna diferencia entre “ahora” y “ahorita”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23038/5481) pare ver si l oque se explica en ellas responde a tu consulta? (Se puede hacer usando la barra del borde superior que dice "Search on Spanish Language") Si no lo has hecho ya, sería una buena idea revisar las secciones [tour], [ask] y [help], para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio

Comment: Para aclarar, preguntas que si se puede usar "ahorita" en medio de una narración para describir algo que sucede en el pasado como por ejemplo "Ayer la puerta estaba cerrada. **Ahorita** llegaron los muchachos. Se les abrió la puerta, pasaron y durmieron en la casa anoche"???

Comment: Gracias RubioRic, justamente mi pregunta es el ejemplo que pones. Busqué la respuesta en Lis otros hilos, pero hacían más buena referencia al uso de “ahorita” como futuro o como coletilla ¿Se puede usar así?

Comment: La expresión *ahorita* es una de las más ambiguas usadas en México, me encantaría poder escribir una respuesta ampliada, desafortunadamente no cuento con el tiempo, pero, la pondré en mi lista de preguntas por responder ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso significa que los niños acaban de llegar.  Y si quieres poner más énfasis en que ya en este momento, puedes decir "ahoritita."

Es correcto de lo que yo he entendido.  Es muy común en México hablar así y dudo que haya regla en su contra en la Academia mexicana o española.